# How can I reverse date time to ajax date time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In javascript I have some datetime like this

```
Date: '2017-07-04'
```

I want to convert it to DateTime like ajax get result.

Expect result like this:

```
'/Date(1565089870830)/'
```

How can I make it possible?

Comment: No, no, no, no. Please don't do this unless you have no option. It would be preferable to have the server serialize and deserialize dates using a proper date format like ISO8601

Comment: Yes, I know. But some time we want to synchronized data. For example, In a list get from ajax. I want to add new Date() for the Field null. I think we should convert it in this situation

Comment: That still wouldn't require you to format the date in this manner. That sounds like a separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.parse()`. This method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC or `NaN` if the string is unrecognized or, in some cases, contains illegal date values (e.g. `2015-02-31`).

```
var date = Date.parse('2017-07-04');
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you're trying to create is a string containing an Epoch timestamp. To create that in JS you can create a Date object from the input string and retrieve the `getTime()` property. Then it's just a matter of concatenating that value in to the format needed. Try this:

```js
var date = new Date('2017-07-04');

var epoch = date.getTime();
var output = `/Date(${epoch})/`;
console.log(output);
```

Presumably you're working with an ASP.Net MVC site, given the date format you're trying to build. One thing to note here is that you don't need to use that format when sending DateTime values back to the server. You can send any string so long as it can be bound to a DateTime instance by the ModelBinder. As such I'd recommend using an ISO8601 format instead.